# Prove by induction that $4^n+5^n+6^n$ is divisible by $15$ for all odd $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, induction

> Prove by induction that $4^n+5^n+6^n$ is divisible by $15$ for all odd $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

**My proof :**
I'm straight going to the induction hypothesis part.

Let for some odd $m(\gt2)\in \mathbb{N}, 15 | 4^m+5^m+6^m$.
Then, $$ 4^m+5^m+6^m = 15q$$ for some $q\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now, $$4^m = 15q-5^m-6^m$$

Since $m$ is odd then the next odd number is $m+2$.

Now, $$ 4^{m+2} + 5^{m+2} + 6^{m+2} \\
= 4^m \cdot 16 + 5^m \cdot 25 + 6^m \cdot 36 \\
= (15q-5^m-6^m) \cdot 16 + 5^m \cdot 25 + 6^m \cdot 36 \\
= 15 \cdot 16q + 9 \cdot 5^m + 20 \cdot 6^m \\
= 15 \cdot 16q + 9 \cdot 5 \cdot 5^{m-1} + 20 \cdot 6 \cdot 6^{m-1} \\
= 15\big( 16q + 3 \cdot 5^{m-1} + 8 \cdot 6^{m-1} \big) \\
\\
\implies  15 | 4^{m+2} + 5^{m+2} + 6^{m+2} $$

Thus from induction the statement is true for every odd $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: That works. Or, without induction, $\,4,5,6\,$ are $\,1, -1, 0 \pmod 3\,$ and $\,-1,0,1 \pmod 5\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for confirmation.

Comment: Stab in the dark: are you concerned about the $m$ to $m + 2$ thing? If it makes you more comfortable, you could try to prove $15 \mid 4^{2n+1} + 5^{2n+1} + 6^{2n+1}$ for $n \ge 0$. That way, this is a traditional induction proof over the natural numbers, and it is appropriate to assume this holds for $n = m$, and prove it holds for $n = m + 1$. Of course, this is still doing basically what you're doing in your proof, just slightly less elegantly.

Comment: @Theo actually in my answer I did what you talked about in your comment. Here I had to get the confirmation first so in hurry I did the rough work that came to my mind instantly.

Comment: @Theo should I edit or leave it as it is?

Comment: @Itachi This answer is fine. Doing it with $2n+1$ is fine too. I personally slightly prefer what you've written, but that's purely a taste thing. Don't worry about editing it. You clearly understand how the induction step works for this problem.

Comment: @Theo alright mate!

Answer (score 1):

**If you know about linear recurrence:** Let $f(n)=4^n+5^n+6^n,$ then you get the recurrence $$\begin{align} 
f(n+3)&=(4+5+6)f(n+2)-(4\cdot 5+4\cdot 6+5\cdot 6)f(n+1)+4\cdot 5\cdot 6 f(n)\\
&=15f(n+2)-74f(n+1)+240f(n)\\&\equiv f(n+1)\pmod{15}
\end{align} $$ So not only is $$f(2k+1)\equiv f(1)=15\equiv 0\pmod {15},$$ but $$f(2k)\equiv f(2)=77\equiv 2\pmod{15},$$ for $k\geq 1.$

---

If $a,b,c$ are integers, and $g(n)=a4^n+b5^n+c6^n,$ you will get the same congruence, $g(n+3)\equiv g(n+1)\pmod {15}.$

---

Even more generally, if $a,b,c,d$ are integers and $3\not\mid d,$ and $h(n)=a(d-1)^n+bd^n+c(d+1)^n,$ you also get:

$$h(n+3)\equiv h(n+1)\pmod {3d}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just a small detail. You proved the induction step $P(m) \implies P(m+2)$ with the hypothesis $m$ odd, $m>2$. If you prove the induction base $m=1$, your proof will be, strictly speaking, incomplete. Because you would have proved

- $P(1)$
- $P(m) \implies P(m+2)$ for odd $m > 2$

which translate in proving:

- $P(1)$
- $P(3) \implies P(5)$
- $P(5) \implies P(7)$
- ...

As you see, you would had missed a link in the chain of implications: $P(1) \implies P(3)$.

You should drop the constraint $m>2$ (that you actually didn't use in your proof).

If you had proved $P(m-2) \implies P(m)$ then the constraint $m > 2$ would be necessary.

Comment: Actually I posted the rough work that I came up at first. Then while answering it formally in my notebook I rephrased everything and Proved it in the right way which is : For any odd $n\in \mathbb{N}, \ n = 2m-1, \text{for some} \ m\in \mathbb{N}$. Thus let, $P(m) $ be the statement that $4^n+5^n+6^n$ is divisible by $15$ where $n=2m-1$. Then I followed the induction steps for $m =1, 2, k(\gt 2) \text{and} \ k+1$.

Comment: @Itachi Just to be clear. That is not "the" right way, but "a" right way. Proving $P(1)$ and $P(m) \implies P(m+2)$ for $m\ge 1$ is a perfect valid way too.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, let $f(n)=4^n+5^n+6^n$. Then
$$
f(n+2)-f(n)=15 \cdot 4^n + 24 \cdot 5^n + 35 \cdot 6^n = 15 \cdot 4^n + 15 \cdot 8 \cdot 5^{n-1} + 15 \cdot 14 \cdot 6^{n-1}
$$
So if $15$ divides $f(n)$, then $15$ divides $f(n+2)$. Note that $n+2$ is the next odd number if $n$ is odd.